# Debugging Node.js with Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to debug Node.js (v0.6.1) with Google's Eclipse debugger plugin for V8. I'm using `Eclipse v4.1.0 on Windows7`. I followed the [Using Eclipse as Node Applications Debugger](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger), but whenever I try to attach to a running Node.js (port 5858) process, I get a pop-up error message saying:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Debug session initialization: Node-5858".
Exception occured in callback
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking into a problem similar to this, this is what I have found

The instructions for setting it up, might just be worth re-reading these to make sure everything is as it should be:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

Do note that when looking around at a similar problem i located this help ticket on google code, it relates to a number of users who are having problems with Node.js on windows:

http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=53

It might be worth just downloading the newest version of Node.js as I believe this now has the fix in place, else download the fix file then mention within the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test for [Nodeclipse](http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/) version 0.2.0 beta.

http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/

> GENERATING OF EXPRESS PROJECT
>
> ```
> Select the [File]-[New]-[Project] menu.
> Select [Node]-[Express Project], and push [Next] button.
> Enter [Project name], and push [Finish] button.
> ```
>
> DEBUGGING
>
> ```
> Open the JavaScript source files that you want to set breakpoints.
> Double-click on the ruler at the left end of the line you want to set a breakpoint.
> If you want to remove a breakpoint, double-click on the ruler again.
> Select the main source file of Node Application on the Project Explorer, open the context menu by right-clicking, select the [Debug As]-[Node Application] menu.
> ```

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. **+** Please be sure to read the [faq#promotion] carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

After creating the project, go to the cmd and provide the filepath of the file which you want to debug.
Now run the command node --debug-brk demo_node.js
(where demo_node.js is filename)

Now come to eclipse side, open the same file and set the break points.
Right click on the source file and select [Debug As]-[Node Application].